# float does not align div elements properly

Tags: css, html, css-float

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="table" style="display:table;width:600px">
      <div style="display:table-row">

         <div style="width:30%;float:left;display:table-cell">Flow ID</div> 
         <div style="width:60%;float:right;display:table-cell">
             <input type="text" name="flowid" size="20" id="flowid"/>
         </div> 
         <div style="width:10%,float:right;display:table-cell">  [Default : 32] </div>
      </div>

      <div style="display:table-row">
          <div style="width:30%;float:left;display:table-cell">Traffic Class</div>
          <div style="width:60%;float:right;display:table-cell">
              <input type="text" name="traffic" size="20" id="traffic"/> 
          </div>          
          <div style="width:10%;float:right;display:table-cell"> [Default : 0] </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.table {
 font: 81.25%/1 arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color:rgb(241,241,241);
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 50%;
 text-align:center;
 border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
}
```

Output I am getting is :

[image]

Why this strange behaviour ?

Althoguh first row seems to be correctly organized but still table-cell elements are not aligned completely to left and right. For second row, I have no clue what's going on ?

I am new in using divs as I used to do all these things with tables so please excuse if missing something trivial.

Comment: 1. Why use a CSS table when a HTML one would be fine

Comment: 2. What is the reason for the floats?

Comment: If you're trying to display a table layout, you should use the <table> element.

Comment: I wouldn't say 'should' as there are many reasons for using a CSS based table. Its just that in this case there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: Table aren't bad if what your trying to do is a table:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877754/best-practice-table-div-list-or-some-combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the floats and you also had a typo in one of the inline styles:

`width:10%,float:right;` should be `width:10%;float:right;`.

Here is it working: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sQ4Nb/

Here is how you should have your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/cS35y/

And here is a HTML table version:
http://jsfiddle.net/53fKu/

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use div elements if you decide to display them like a table?
You may try something like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ2JA)

```
<ul id="wrapper">
    <li>
        <div style="width:30%;" class="cell">Flow ID</div>
        <div style="width:55%;" class="cell">
            <input type="text" name="flowid" size="20" id="flowid" />
        </div>
        <div style="width:15%;" class="cell">[Default : 32]</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="width:30%;" class="cell">Traffic Class</div>
        <div style="width:55%;" class="cell">
            <input type="text" name="traffic" size="20" id="traffic" />
        </div>
        <div style="width:15%;" class="cell">[Default : 0]</div>
    </li>
</ul>

#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    list-style: none;
}
.cell {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `li` tag is definitely not appropriate for a table row.

Comment: Not a great solution plus you're missing an opening and closing UL tag.

Comment: Why is li not appropriate? I've seen many high quality sites which use list elements for such operations. Also the div instead of ul isn't a big deal since both use `display: block`. Look at my jsfiddle, it's working just fine without using div as table elements. I really dont see any use in `<div style="display:table-row">` over `<tr>`?

Comment: I changed it to `<ul>` to take your objection into account.